# Communication between Portlet Factory and JSR 168

Tags: portlet

First at all, sorry for my english

I have one portlet in Portlet Factory in one page in one .war and have another portlet in JSR 168 in other page and other .war

I need to Portlet Factory redirect, using command button, to Portlet JSR 168

Please i spend two weeks try to find the solution

And again sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

One way out for you is portlet eventing. Now life would have been easier had you been on JSR286 since you could use standard eventing. Some JSR 168 portlets container/portals have proprietary eventing mechanisms like WebSphere Portal has cooperative mechanism. 
Another point, when your portlets are deployed, it does not matter if  you have created them using Portlet Factory or RAD or any other tool. You are then dealing with just portlets.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster points out, this would be easier with JSR286 portlets (WEF and non-WEF) as the eventing is standard,  but it's not impossible with JSR168, if you're limited to that version in the short term.

Web Experience Factory (WEF) / formerly known as WebSphere Portlet Factory (WPF) has Cooperative Portlet Source and Target builders to help automate the process of setting up portlet events, whether JSR286 standard based events or JSR168 IBM Portal specific (WSDL defined) events.    If you're still looking for how to solve this issue (unlikely since the question is rather old - sorry about that) then I suggest looking at the Cooperative Portlet Source and Target builders for the WPF/WEF side and the portlet event support in your non-WEF tooling for the other JSR portlet.

I hope that info helps,
..Mike Burati 
The postings on this site are my own and do not necessarily represent the positions, strategies, or opinions of IBM.